# Getting error while using mulitple in drop down list using Angular.js

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I have one big issue.I need to select multiple value from drop down list ,for that i used `bootstrap-multiselect.js` getting the below error.

```
angularjs.js:107 TypeError: a.forEach is not a function
    at u.writeValue (angularjs.js:273)
    at f.$render (angularjs.js:285)
    at Object.<anonymous> (angularjs.js:265)
    at n.$digest (angularjs.js:130)
    at n.$apply (angularjs.js:133)
    at HTMLInputElement.<anonymous> (angularjs.js:253)
    at HTMLInputElement.m.event.dispatch (jquery.js:4670)
    at HTMLInputElement.r.handle (jquery.js:4338)
```

here i have the below button.when user will click this the drop down list is loading dynamically.

```
<input type='button' class='btn btn-xs btn-green' value='Send' ng-click="sendVoucherCode(code.voucher_code_id,code.expired_date,code.customer_name);" ng-hide="sendButton">
```

when user is clicking the above button the below drop down list has to load dynamically .

```
<select class="form-control"  id="lstFruits" ng-model="voucher_code" ng-options="code.name for code in listOfCode track by code.value " ng-change="removeBorder('lstFruits')"  multiple="multiple">
 </select>
```

The controller side code for the above drop down list is given below.

```
    $scope.sendVoucherCode=function(voucherid,expierdate,cname){
        $scope.listOfCode=[{
        name:'Select Voucher Code',
        value:''
    }]
    $scope.voucher_code=$scope.listOfCode[0];
        var code={'voucher_code_id':voucherid};
            $http({
                method:'POST',
                url:"php/getVoucherNotifyCode.php",
                data:code,
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
            }).then(function successCallback(response){
                console.log('voucher code',response.data);
                $scope.codeImage=response.data[0].image;
                $scope.arrCode=response.data[0].generated_code.split(',');
                for(var i=0;i<$scope.arrCode.length;i++){
                    var data={'name':$scope.arrCode[i],'value':$scope.arrCode[i]};
                    $scope.listOfCode.push(data);
                }
            },function errorCallback(response) {
            })
    }
$('#lstFruits').multiselect({
           includeSelectAllOption: true
      });
```

Here when the above function is called the error is coming and drop down field is not opening.Here also i need when user will click on the send button the dynamic value will load inside the drop down list and user can fetch one/mupltiple value,those value will again collected inside the controller side function.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Seems like voucher_code is not bind with an array. If multiselect is bind with an object this error arise.

Comment: @ Wasaaq : check my updated post again.still throwing the same issue.When i am removing the `multiple="multiple"` the error is not coming.Do you have any solution.Please edit this.